# How to implement drag & drop on a ul in javascript while keeping other functions (delete,edit,add)?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I started to learn javascript and I created a basic to do list/task list. I manage to implement edit and delete for a single element and now I wanted to implement drag & drop. I manage to do that but after I swap 1 element delete/edit stop working and honestly I don't know how to fix that.

Here's my  html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>To Do List</title>
    <style>
        /* Prevent the text contents of draggable elements from being selectable. */

        [draggable] {
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            /* Required to make elements draggable in old WebKit */
            -khtml-user-drag: element;
            -webkit-user-drag: element;
        }
        /* Edit Task */

        ul li input[type=text] {
            display: none;
        }

        ul li.editMode input[type=text] {
            display: block;
        }

        ul li.editMode label {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<h>My list:</h>

<body>
    <p>

        <input id="new-item" type="text">
        <button>Add</button>
    </p>

    <ul id="list">
    </ul>

    <script src="v2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my javascript code:

```
var taskInput = document.getElementById("new-item");
var addButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var listHolder = document.getElementById("list");

//New Task List Item
var createNewElement = function(taskString) {
    //Create list item
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    //label
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    //edit input
    var editInput = document.createElement("input");
    //edit button
    var editButton = document.createElement("button");
    //delete button
    var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

    //Modify each element
    editInput.type = "text";
    editButton.innerText = "\u270E";
    editButton.className = "edit";
    deleteButton.innerText = "\u2716";
    deleteButton.className = "delete";

    label.innerText = taskString;

    //Append each element
    listItem.appendChild(label);
    listItem.appendChild(editInput);
    listItem.appendChild(editButton);
    listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);



    return listItem;
}
//Addd a new  task into the list
var addTask = function() {

    //Create a new list item with the text from input
    var listItem = createNewElement(taskInput.value);
    listItem.classList.add("column");
    listItem.setAttribute("draggable", "true");



    listHolder.appendChild(listItem);
    // Append listItem to bindTaskEvents


    bindTaskEvents(listItem);

    //Drag and drop
    listItem.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
    listItem.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false)
    listItem.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    listItem.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    listItem.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
    listItem.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);

    //Reset input value
    taskInput.value = "";

}

//Edit an existing task
var editTask = function() {

    var listItem = this.parentNode;
    var editInput = listItem.querySelector("input[type=text]");
    var label = listItem.querySelector("label");
    var containsClass = listItem.classList.contains("editMode");
    //if parent class is .editMode
    if (containsClass) {
        //switch from .editMode
        //make label text become the input's value
        label.innerText = editInput.value;
    } else {
        //switch to .editMode
        //the input values become the label's text
        editInput.value = label.innerText;
    }
    //toggle .editMode on parrent
    listItem.classList.toggle("editMode");

}

//Delete existing task
var deleteTask = function() {

    var listItem = this.parentNode;
    var ul = listItem.parentNode;

    //Remove the parent list item from the ul
    ul.removeChild(listItem);

}

//bind buttons to events
var bindTaskEvents = function(taskListItem) {
    var editButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.edit");
    var deleteButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.delete");

    //bind editTask to editButton

    if (editButton == null)
        return;
    editButton.onclick = editTask;
    //bind editTask to deleteButton
    deleteButton.onclick = deleteTask;

}

//Set the click handler to the addTask function
addButton.addEventListener("click", addTask);


//Cycle over listHolder ul list items
for (var i = 0; i < listHolder.children.length; i++) {
    bindTaskEvents(listHolder.children[i]);
}



var dragSrcEl = null;

function handleDragStart(e) {
    dragSrcEl = this;

    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);

}

function handleDragOver(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
    }

    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'; // See the section on the DataTransfer object.

    return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
    // this / e.target is the current hover target.
    this.classList.add('over');
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
    this.classList.remove('over'); // this / e.target is previous target        element.
}

function handleDrop(e) {
    // this/e.target is current target element.

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
    }

    // Don't do anything if dropping the same column we're dragging.
    if (dragSrcEl != this) {
        // Set the source column's HTML to the HTML of the column we dropped on.
        dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    }

    return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
    // this/e.target is the source node.

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: this mayhelp you https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Comment: @gusaindpk that's the guilde i used to implement drag&drop.

Comment: OK will check it..

Comment: updated the js code, let know if it helps you also accept the ans using right tick mark :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the delete and edit events again using **(in handleDrop function as dom is updated)**

```
                      for (var i = 0; i < listHolder.children.length; i++) {
                      bindTaskEvents(listHolder.children[i]);
                  }
```

I have updated the code please check. **Update**

```
              var taskInput = document.getElementById("new-item");
              var addButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
              var listHolder = document.getElementById("list");

              //New Task List Item
              var createNewElement = function(taskString) {
                  //Create list item
                  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
                  //label
                  var label = document.createElement("label");
                  //edit input
                  var editInput = document.createElement("input");
                  //edit button
                  var editButton = document.createElement("button");
                  //delete button
                  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

                  //Modify each element
                  editInput.type = "text";
                  editButton.innerText = "\u270E";
                  editButton.className = "edit";
                  deleteButton.innerText = "\u2716";
                  deleteButton.className = "delete";

                  label.innerText = taskString;

                  //Append each element
                  listItem.appendChild(label);
                  listItem.appendChild(editInput);
                  listItem.appendChild(editButton);
                  listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);



                  return listItem;
              }
              //Addd a new  task into the list
              var addTask = function() {

                  //Create a new list item with the text from input
                  var listItem = createNewElement(taskInput.value);
                  listItem.classList.add("column");
                  listItem.setAttribute("draggable", "true");



                  listHolder.appendChild(listItem);
                  // Append listItem to bindTaskEvents


                  bindTaskEvents(listItem);

                  //Drag and drop
                  listItem.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
                  listItem.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false)
                  listItem.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
                  listItem.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
                  listItem.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
                  listItem.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);

                  //Reset input value
                  taskInput.value = "";

              }

              //Edit an existing task
              var editTask = function() {

                  var listItem = this.parentNode;
                  var editInput = listItem.querySelector("input[type=text]");
                  var label = listItem.querySelector("label");
                  var containsClass = listItem.classList.contains("editMode");
                  //if parent class is .editMode
                  if (containsClass) {
                      //switch from .editMode
                      //make label text become the input's value
                      label.innerText = editInput.value;
                  } else {
                      //switch to .editMode
                      //the input values become the label's text
                      editInput.value = label.innerText;
                  }
                  //toggle .editMode on parrent
                  listItem.classList.toggle("editMode");

              }

              //Delete existing task
              var deleteTask = function() {

                  var listItem = this.parentNode;
                  var ul = listItem.parentNode;

                  //Remove the parent list item from the ul
                  ul.removeChild(listItem);

              }

              //bind buttons to events
              var bindTaskEvents = function(taskListItem) {
                  var editButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.edit");
                  var deleteButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.delete");

                  //bind editTask to editButton

                  if (editButton == null)
                      return;
                  editButton.onclick = editTask;
                  //bind editTask to deleteButton
                  deleteButton.onclick = deleteTask;

              }

              //Set the click handler to the addTask function
              addButton.addEventListener("click", addTask);


              //Cycle over listHolder ul list items
              for (var i = 0; i < listHolder.children.length; i++) {
                  bindTaskEvents(listHolder.children[i]);
              }



              var dragSrcEl = null;

              function handleDragStart(e) {
                  dragSrcEl = this;

                  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
                  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);

              }

              function handleDragOver(e) {
                  if (e.preventDefault) {
                      e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
                  }

                  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'; // See the section on the DataTransfer object.

                  return false;
              }

              function handleDragEnter(e) {
                  // this / e.target is the current hover target.
                  this.classList.add('over');
              }

              function handleDragLeave(e) {
                  this.classList.remove('over'); // this / e.target is previous target        element.
              }

              function handleDrop(e) {
                  // this/e.target is current target element.

                  if (e.stopPropagation) {
                      e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
                  }

                  // Don't do anything if dropping the same column we're dragging.
                  if (dragSrcEl != this) {
                      // Set the source column's HTML to the HTML of the column we dropped on.
                      dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                      this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
                      //Cycle over listHolder ul list items
                      for (var i = 0; i < listHolder.children.length; i++) {
                          bindTaskEvents(listHolder.children[i]);
                      }
                  }

                  return false;
              }

              function handleDragEnd(e) {
                  // this/e.target is the source node
            }
```